# What's the best way to diagnose Visual Studio slowness?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, profiling

I want to file a Microsoft Connect issue with the Visual Studio team, but I am not sure what to include that is helpful.  Since starting my new job in February, I have experienced a number of simply awful performance issues with Visual Studio 2012:

1. "Could not complete the action" error message dialog.  Sometimes, after clicking OK (the only option), the error message dialog comes back right away.  Visual Studio does not say what "action" it was trying to complete.
2. "Preparing Solution..." dialog sometimes takes forever.
3. Occasionally, Visual Studio will crash and re-start in the middle of a long build.
4. "Operation could not be completed" error message dialog.  Sometimes, after clicking OK (the only option), the error message dialog comes back right away.  Visual Studio does not say what "action" it was trying to complete, but while it is thinking, Visual Studio is basically locked up and I can't do anything.

Visual Studio 2012 comes with a [Visual Studio Feedback Tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8a5aac8-0418-4f88-9d34-bdbe2c4cfe72), but the reviews are awful.  [PerfWatson](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2011/08/24/how-we-use-your-perfwatson-data-to-identify-unresponsive-areas.aspx) also isn't immediately helpful (unless I am missing some key feature, it is only useful to the Visual Studio product team, and not useful for solving immediate, urgent problems I face).

I have searched Stack Overflow for each of these issues and feel like I have tried everything I can.  But all the answers on Stack Overflow so far focus on heuristics; common solutions to the associated problems.  They don't focus on teaching you how to fish and figuring out how to diagnose the root cause of the problem.

When I go to [Help > Troubleshooting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-ES/vstudio/ff716700), to see what Microsoft recommends, a Visual Studio 2010 troubleshooting page opens.

I tried running SysInternals Process Monitor, but the only weird thing I saw was that csc.exe was making a TON of Windows Registry calls for HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Cryptopgraphy\Defaults*.  I tried googling about this to understand what could make csc.exe do this, and didn't find any useful information.

What can I do to help Microsoft diagnose my specific issues, without giving them my *.sln file and source code?

I have also tried devenv.exe /safemode, and this sometimes fixes some performance issues, but it still seems very slow.  Further, when I exit out of /safemode and try to re-open the solution with plug-ins loaded, the solution hangs, and I have to kill it.  Re-loading Visual Studio a second time then makes the problem go away.

I feel like [this poor guy](http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_meko8n2MAD1rpn6xxo1_400.gif).  Please, no trolling suggestions to install xemacs, SharpDevelop, etc.  I want to use the same tools as my coworkers.

Comment: did you try running it in safemode?

Comment: Visual Studio needs a good machine to work on. We have I5 2500k machines with 4GB 1333 mhz RAM running X64 Windows 7. Our main solution has 23 projects, and sometimes I get out of memory while running 2 instances of Visual Studio. We're just waiting our 8 GB modules to arrive by monday.

Comment: There might be many cases for poor performance of vs on your machine: 1.Low available main memory  2. Corrupted Installation of VS  3. Missing updates for VS/ windows 4.Memory Leaks in application you are developing consuming all of main memory. 5.Virus on your machine.   I can't affirm what's applicable for your case. Just try these in order, till you got solution : 1. restart system run other projects, check if your application memory leak is culprit. 2. Reinstall VS. 3.update vs/windows update 4. check for viruses 5. if not all works, hell yes, you will need to increase RAM :)

Comment: @HighCore One co-worker has the exact same machine as me, and has no complaints.  Another co-worker has the same machine with Windows 8 installed.  I have an i7-3520M @ 2.9ghz with 2x4GB@1600mhz.  The only "weird" thing I have is the fancy $99 Logitech Performance Mouse MX; this mouse has a kinetic scroll wheel so that the mouse wheel continues to spin even after you take your hand off it.  Some applications do not behave well with this, but plugging in a different mouse seems to change nothing.

Comment: Honestly, I think you're better off if you back up your personal data, ghost a coworker's computer and go on from there. Diagnosing these things is usually just a waste of time.

Comment: @Pranav memory pressure does not seem to be an issue.  I have Windows AppFabric running on my development machine, and it is capped at 1GB.  Visual Studio peak working set is under .75GB.

Comment: @Yandros Uninstalling and re-installing did not work.

Comment: That's not what I meant. You said that your coworkers' computers were all the same as yours, right? So backup your personal data, make an image of one of theirs (with Norton Ghost or any other [disk cloning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_cloning) software) and restore it on your computer. If you still have issues after that, it's a hardware problem.

Comment: For the "Preparing Solution... takes forever issue"... Here's a good practice that I've tried, Unload every project in the solution before closing VS.